# Java Method to retrieve nested fields in JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, nested

I am trying to write a utility method that I can use everywhere in my code to retrieve certain parts of a json. Here is my method:

```
public static <T> T getResponseObject(String resourceResponse, String jsonField, Class<T> responseClass) {
    T responseObject = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse).getJSONObject(jsonField);
        responseObject = mapper.readValue(jsonResponse.toString(), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(responseClass));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO error, cannot read json response", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("JSON API error", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseObject;
}
```

And here's a sample JSON response:

```
{
    "User":{
        "identityList":{
            "identity":[
                {
                    "firstName":"MICHAEL",
                    "lastName":"JAMESON",
                    "gender":"MALE",
                    "dateOfBirth":"1961-05-18T00:00:00.000+0000",
                },
                {
                    "firstName":"KELLY",
                    "lastName":"JAMESON",
                    "gender":"FEMALE",
                    "dateOfBirth":"1951-04-01T00:00:43.000+0000",
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "resultCode": true
}
```

So if I wanted to get the `identity` field I would have to traverse down 3 layers to get the array. I have an idea of how to resolve this which is by setting the method input as a `List<String>` which would look like this:

```
+-------+--------------+
| Index |    Value     |
+-------+--------------+
|     0 | User         |
|     1 | identityList |
|     2 | identity     |
+-------+--------------+
```

And I would just iterate through this list till i got to the final field. However, this doesn't really seem to be the best approach. Is there anyway to access the nested field, in this case `identity`, in 1 call without having to traverse down by doing multiple `getJSONObject` calls?

Comment: I dont think so you need to be on a certain json object to retrieve the content, in your case a jsonARRAY within identityList and User. Other solution with be reconstructing your json

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't make more sense to unmarshall it all to a POJO and use java methods to find fields?

Answer (score 0):

Here try something like this. I like getting json out like this in java because it is easy to do and easy to read what your doing

```
jsonResponseObject.getJSONObject(“User”).getJSONObject(“identityList”).getJSONArray(“identity”);
```

You can do what you want with this. For a example on how I would use this;

```
 myInt = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Level1").getInt("myInt");
```